# Why is SCHAR_MIN defined as -127 in C99?

Tags: c, char, language-lawyer, c99

§5.2.4.2.1 of C99 defines `SCHAR_MIN` as -127 and `SCHAR_MAX` as 127. Should not the range for an 8 bit signed integer be -128 to +127?

The `limits.h` for my compiler defines SCHAR_MIN as `(-1 << ((CHAR_BIT)-1))`, which is -128 given CHAR_BIT is 8.

Is there any reason why `SCHAR_MIN` was defined -127 and not -128 ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It doesn't actually define `SCHAR_MIN` as -127, it defines the *minimum range* of signed characters to -127..127.

It does this because it has to be able to handle the *other* two encoding schemes for signed numbers, those being ones' complement and sign/magnitude. Both of these have a positive *and* negative zero, stealing away the -128 you find in two's complement.

ISO C (C99), section `6.2.6.2/2`, states that an implementation must choose one of these three different representations for signed integral data types:

- two's complement;
- ones' complement; or
- sign/magnitude

The two's complement implementations far outweigh the others but the others *do* exist.

In all those representations, positive numbers are identical, the only difference being the negative numbers.

To get the negative representation for a positive number, you:

- invert all bits then add one for two's complement.
- invert all bits for ones' complement.
- invert just the sign bit for sign/magnitude.

You can see this in the table below, for both 5 and 0:

```
number | two's complement    | ones' complement    | sign/magnitude
=======|=====================|=====================|====================
     5 | 0000 0000 0000 0101 | 0000 0000 0000 0101 | 0000 0000 0000 0101
    -5 | 1111 1111 1111 1011 | 1111 1111 1111 1010 | 1000 0000 0000 0101
       |                     |                     |
     0 | 0000 0000 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 0000 0000
    -0 | 0000 0000 0000 0000 | 1111 1111 1111 1111 | 1000 0000 0000 0000
           (no difference)        (both of these have distinct +/-0)
```

Comment: Technically, it is *Ones'* complement, not *One's* complement.  There is a difference :-).

Comment: My reference is *The Art of Computer Programming*.  The difference being that *Ones'* complement is with respect to a long string of ones, whereas *Two's* complement is not with respect to a long string of twos.

Comment: @Alok: my authority was the top eight hits on Google :-) But I checked volume 2 of TAOCP and you're right. I'd also be more inclined to listen to Knuth than a _hundred_ internet pages, so I'll modify it. I would note that the ISO standard itself uses Knuth's notation. Or should that be Knuths' notation? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: It should be Knuths' only if you're referring to a long string of Knuths.

Comment: You take a one's complement for each digit, so the entire number is a complement of many ones, making it ones' complement.

Comment: Have there ever actually been any conforming implementations where the number of values for `char` was not a power of 2, or where the number of values for `signed char` was not at least 256?

Comment: @supercat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276957/are-there-any-non-twos-complement-implementations-of-c

Comment: @paxdiablo: The one non-two's-complement machine I saw there was a 36-bit machine whose `char` type is unsigned and holds 512 distinct values, and whose signed char type holds 511 values.