# Simple C data types

Tags: c, types, primitive-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The difference of int8_t, int_least8_t and int_fast8_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254051/the-difference-of-int8-t-int-least8-t-and-int-fast8-t)

I'm a quite confused. I think... (correct me if I'm wrong)

```
u_int8_t = unsigned short ?
u_int16_t = unsigned int ?
u_int32_t = unsigned long ?
u_int64_t = unsigned long long ?

int8_t = short ?
int16_t = int ?
int32_t = long ?
int64_t = long long ?
```

Then what does `int_fast8_t` mean? `int_fastN_t`? `int_least8_t`?

Comment: Check that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254051/the-difference-of-int8-t-int-least8-t-and-int-fast8-t

Answer (score 2):

I writing where int is of 16-bit:

```
u_int8_t = unsigned char  
u_int16_t = unsigned int
u_int32_t = unsigned long int
u_int64_t = unsigned long long int 

int8_t =  char
int16_t = int 
int32_t = long int
int64_t = long long int
```

---

Q:  "Then what does int_fast8_t mean? int_fastN_t? int_least8_t?"

As dan04 states in [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254051/the-difference-of-int8-t-int-least8-t-and-int-fast8-t/5254321#5254321):

> Suppose you have a C compiler for a 36-bit system, with `char` = 9
>   bits, `short` = 18 bits, `int` = 36 bits, and `long` = 72 bits.  Then
>
> - `int8_t` *does not exist*, because there is no way to satisfy the constraint of having *exactly* 8 value bits with no padding.
> - `int_least8_t` is a typedef of `char`.  NOT of `short` or `int`, because the standard requires the *smallest* type with at least 8
>     bits.
> - `int_fast8_t` can be anything.  It's likely to be a typedef of `int` if the "native" size is considered to be "fast".

---

If you are in `Linux` most these are defined in `/usr/include/linux/coda.h`. e.g.

```
#ifndef __BIT_TYPES_DEFINED__
#define __BIT_TYPES_DEFINED__
typedef signed char       int8_t;
typedef unsigned char       u_int8_t;
typedef short            int16_t;
typedef unsigned short     u_int16_t;
typedef int          int32_t;
typedef unsigned int       u_int32_t;
#endif
```

And

```
#if defined(DJGPP) || defined(__CYGWIN32__)
#ifdef KERNEL
typedef unsigned long u_long;
typedef unsigned int u_int;
typedef unsigned short u_short;
typedef u_long ino_t;
typedef u_long dev_t;
typedef void * caddr_t;
#ifdef DOS
typedef unsigned __int64 u_quad_t;
#else 
typedef unsigned long long u_quad_t;
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

These are all specified in the C99 standard (section 7.18).

The `[u]intN_t` types are generic types (in the ISO C standard) where `N` represents a bit width (8, 16, etc). 8-bit is not necessarily a `short` or `char` since shorts/ints/longs/etc are defined to have a *minimum* range (not bitwidth) and may not be two's complement.

These newer types *are* two's complement regardless of the encoding of the more common types, which may be ones' complement or sign/magnitude ( see [Representation of negative numbers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952123/representation-of-negative-numbers-in-c/3952262#3952262) and [Why is SCHAR_MIN defined as -127 in C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010040/why-is-schar-min-defined-as-127-in-c99/8010063#8010063)).

`fast` and `least` are exactly what they sound like, fast-minimum-width types and types of at least a given width.

The standard also details which type are required and which are optional.

Comment: In Linux system, I didn't find `int_fastN_t`. Why so? I search using `/usr/include$ grep 'int_fastN_t' * -R`.

Comment: @Grijesh, there _are_ no `blahN_t` types, the `N` is a placeholder in the standard for 8, 16, and so on. Search for `int_fast8_t` instead - they should all be together (and referenced from `inttypes.h`).

Comment: Yes, `int_fast8_t` present but in `stdint.h`...in my system declaration are in `coda.h`! - Thanks paxdiablo :) voted-up to you

Comment: Sorry, my bad, `stdint` holds the types, `inttypes` holds the format specifiers for `printf/scanf`.

Comment: Note that the `fast` and `least` types are not optional; the exact width types (`int8_t` et al) are optional in the sense that if the implementation uses 9-bit `char`, there won't be an `int8_t` type.  If the implementation supports an 8-bit integer type, `int8_t` is not optional.