# Why is the range of signed char is different in C and C++?

Tags: c, c++11

Why the range of `signed char` is different in C and C++ ?
  In C the range is `-128 t0 127` and in C++ it is `-127 to 127' but on the other hand the unsigned ranges are same. why ?

Comment: Who told you this? Because say this to them ... "No."

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898688/range-of-signed-char

Comment: I already checked and then I asked this question. @simrandhamija

Comment: Yeah , they are , I have been reading C++ with Bjarne Stroustrup and its clearly mentioned over there ($6.2.3) @Ben

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010040/why-is-schar-min-defined-as-127-in-c99

Comment: THANKS @JohnBollinger

Comment: @DeveshPratapSingh: That is not the C++ standard, so whatever it says is not binding to what C++ the language is. Voted to close as unclear since you asked with incorrect assumptions, without citing any sources, and then asked why those assumptions were what they were.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are mistaken. The **guaranteed** minimum value for signed char is in fact -127 in both languages. Quote from C11 standard (draft [N1570](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1p1)):

> - minimum value for an object of type signed char
>
>   ```
>     SCHAR_MIN                                -127
>   ```

Do note that the actual absolute minimum value is implementation defined and may be greater:

> ... Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.

And on processors that have 8 bit byte and two's complement representation (which is rather common), the minimum value will almost certainly be -128 in both C and C++. The reason why only -127 is guaranteed, is because it allows a non two's complement representation to be supported.

Answer (score 5):

The text referenced in the comments, refers to the fact that the `c++` standard does not guide how to implement signed char, ie. it can be implemented as 1's complement giving you the value -127 -> 127 (with +0 and -0).

> The 256 values represented by an 8-bit byte can be interpreted as the values 0 to 255 or as the values −127 to 127 . No, not −128 to 127 as one might expect: the c++ standard leaves open the possibility of ones-compliment hardware and eliminates one value, thus the use of -128 is non-portable.

It doesn't say a char is -127 -> 127, it says it **might** be. Yes, if you want portability with every standard conforming system, you need to consider the possibility of a 1's complement implementation of `char`. In reality, no-one ever has this ...

You should be more worried about things like how some hardware implements a 16 bit char ...

Comment: Thanks for your time dude! and the answer to your last line is <uchar.h> .

Answer (score -2):

I'm not an expert, but I can't find a reference to the c++ range being -127 to 127. Everything I see says it is also -128 to 127. Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: here comes the text - "The 256 values represented by an 8-bit byte can be interpreted as the values 0 to 255 or as the val-
ues −127 to 127 . No, not −128 to 127 as one might expect ". This is what its written here, you can check yourself. I already mentioned the section and subsections above.

Comment: -127 to 127 is the required *minimum* range. It is allowed to have a wider range.

Comment: Sorry, -1. You can't generally answer C++ language questions by link to documentation for a specific compiler. My compiler's signed `char` has a range of -127 to 127, which is perfectly legal C++.

Comment: @GManNickG: Yes, it's perfectly legal -- but it's surprising. What compiler uses that range? Assuming a 2's-complement representation, what happens if you do `signed char sc = -127; --sc; std::cout << "sc = " << (int)sc << "\n";`? (I'm aware the behavior is undefined.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: ...I admit, it was my brain compiler. :)